# json array into json array - Python

Tags: python

I have the code which worked well until the payload changed.

```
field_types =   [
  ('subject', str),
  ('type', str)
]

#reading a raw csv file
output = []
with open('file.csv','r',encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as f:
    for row in csv.DictReader(f):
        row.update((key, conversion(row[key]))
        for key, conversion in field_types)
        output.append(row)
    with open('file.json','w') as outfile: #storing records as json
        json.dump(output,outfile,sort_keys = True, indent = 4)
```

The outcome was saved nicely:

```
    {
        "subject": "1",
        "type": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject": "1",
        "type": "3"
    }
]
```

The current requirement that it should be saved as i.e. I guess as a jsonarray within an array. Have you had this situation? How to achieve it?

```
    {
        "subject": 
       {
            "id": "1"
            },
        "type": "2"
    },
    {
        "subject": 
            {
            "id": "1"
            },
        "type": "3"
    }
]
```

Comment: You could create a function for the conversion type of `subject` that creates the desired `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
def str2dict(s):
    return dict(id=s)

field_types =   [
  ('subject', str2dict),
  ('type', str)
]
```